# Why does popper jump to top-left corner when underlying component re-renders?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, use-effect, popper.js, slate.js

I am using the Material-UI Popper component (which in turn uses popper.js) to create a hovering toolbar. For the most part it is working well, except for one odd behavior:

1. Select some text: the hovering toolbar appears above the text - as expected.
2. Select any button in the toolbar: the appropriate action is performed. However the toolbar jumps to the top-left corner of the window. See below.

[image]

You can try out this behavior in [my Storybook](https://nareshbhatia.github.io/react-force/?path=/story/slate-editor-slateeditor--slate-editor-story) - just select some text and click on one of the "T" buttons.

The basic issue centers around positioning of the popper:

1. When user selects some text, a fake virtual element is created and passed to the popper as an anchor element. Popper uses this `anchorEl` to position the hovering toolbar. So far so good.
2. When the user clicks on a button in the toolbar, the hovering toolbar jumps to the top-left of the window.

I am guessing this is happening because the anchor element is somehow lost when the underlying component re-renders. I don't know why, but this is just my theory. Can someone help me solve this issue?

The code that computes the `anchorEl` sits inside a React `useEffect()`. I have made sure that the dependency list for the `useEffect` is accurate. I can see that when the toolbar jumps, the `useEffect()` is NOT being called, which means that `anchorEl` is not being recomputed. This leads me to believe that the toolbar should stay intact in its current position and not jump to (0,0). But that's not happening :-(.

Here's the `useEffect()` code inside the toolbar component. You can find the full code in [my repo](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/react-force/blob/master/packages/slate-editor/src/components/HoverToolbar.tsx#L57-L79). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (editMode === 'toolbar') {
        if (isTextSelected) {
            const domSelection = window.getSelection();
            if (domSelection === null || domSelection.rangeCount === 0) {
                return;
            }
            const domRange = domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
            const rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();
            setAnchorEl({
                clientWidth: rect.width,
                clientHeight: rect.height,
                getBoundingClientRect: () =>
                    domRange.getBoundingClientRect(),
            });
            setToolbarOpen(true);
        } else {
            setToolbarOpen(false);
        }
    } else {
        setToolbarOpen(false);
    }
}, [editMode, isTextSelected, selection, selectionStr]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `domRange` is no longer valid after [toggleBlock](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/react-force/blob/master/packages/slate-editor/src/transforms/toggleBlock.ts) does its work (due to dom nodes getting replaced), so `getBoundingClientRect` is no longer returning anything meaningful.

You should be able to fix this by redoing the work of getting the range within the anchorEl's `getBoundingClientRect`. Perhaps something like the following (I didn't try to execute it, so no guarantee that there aren't minor errors):

```
const getSelectionRange = () => {
  const domSelection = window.getSelection();
  if (domSelection === null || domSelection.rangeCount === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return domSelection.getRangeAt(0);
};
useEffect(() => {
  if (editMode === "toolbar") {
    if (isTextSelected) {
      const domRange = getSelectionRange();
      if (domRange === null) {
        return;
      }
      const rect = domRange.getBoundingClientRect();
      setAnchorEl({
        clientWidth: rect.width,
        clientHeight: rect.height,
        getBoundingClientRect: () => {
          const innerDomRange = getSelectionRange();
          return innerDomRange === null
            ? null
            : innerDomRange.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
      });
      setToolbarOpen(true);
    } else {
      setToolbarOpen(false);
    }
  } else {
    setToolbarOpen(false);
  }
}, [editMode, isTextSelected, selection, selectionStr]);
```

Comment: You nailed it, Ryan! Works like a charm now. Thank you so much!